# Can SDL run on the Atari Mint?

Tags: c, graphics, sdl, legacy

I am interested in building a game to run on the Atari Mint which doesn't have a graphics card. Therefore, I was wondering if it was possible to run code that uses the SDL_Renderer on the Atari Mint that does not have a graphics card?

ANSWER: The platform was the Atari Mint and it is currently not supported

SEE: https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation#Supported_platforms

Comment: You'll have a hard time seeing anything without a gpu.

Comment: Is it possible just to render something easy like a primitive?

Comment: terms as "old legacy computer" are too vague, do have an Altair 8800? an i686 PC_AT? an old x86 (without the x86_64 extension), with the allmighty system bus. some people, specially gamers, though rare here, will call even a 2nd gen Intel Core i5 a "legacy" cpu.

Comment: [Supported Platforms](https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation#Supported_platforms)

Answer (score 1):

SDL for Atari Mint **is** supported since 2014, but you need some CPU power. See https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/README.MiNT.